# SQL server hanged suddenly - all DB connections are active but no response - SQL server 2016

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2016

I am a Java developer. Since I am new to SQL server, I have limited knowledge on it. I am trying to find out the root cause why our SQL server suddenly hanged and It became normal after restart

**Symptoms:**

~ Java threads started getting stuck, figured out that the Java JDBC connections started hanging without any response from DB which caused threads to stuck

~ All connections (around 100 ) were active until SQL server was restarted. Finally, DB connections were closed by DB after restart. Java JDBC connection received 'Connection reset by peer' AFTER DB was restarted

Impact duration : 5 hours (until restart)

**Tech stack:**
Java spring boot running on weblogic. ORM: hibernate

SQL server 2016

**Limitation**:
Team had restarted the SQL server before we can export any statistics from DB and even doubtful whether we were able to run statistic SQL queries before SQL server restarted as the DB was hanged already

**Findings/actions:**
After DB was restarted, I tried to extract statistics from **dm_exec_query_stats**, however, it tracks queries based on last run time only. There was no result for affected period. Same scenario for **dm_os_waiting_tasks** as well.
Server team say that the CPU and Memory usage were normal (I still to receive complete report)

Could see no error/problem from Windows event log and cluster logs. They look normal

Some Google sources say that some queries may consume complete CPU which may make SQL server to hang, some others say that some queries might have made blocking.

It may look simple or common for SQL server experts/DBA, however, I have googled for finding out relevant issue and resolution, however they doesn't seem to help

Just guiding me to refer any document or expert advise will be great. Let me know if additional info needed. Thanks in advance !

Tried these queries but no joy

```
        SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query], dbid, deqs.*
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
    where deqs.last_execution_time between '2020-09-29 13:16:52.710' and '2020-09-29 23:16:52.710'
     ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC ;



         SELECT 
        qs.sql_handle,
        qs.execution_count,
        qs.total_worker_time AS Total_CPU,
        total_CPU_inSeconds = --Converted from microseconds
            qs.total_worker_time/1000000,
        average_CPU_inSeconds = --Converted from microseconds
            (qs.total_worker_time/1000000) / qs.execution_count,
        qs.total_elapsed_time,
        total_elapsed_time_inSeconds = --Converted from microseconds
            qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000,
        st.text,qs.query_hash,
        qp.query_plan
    FROM
        sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
    CROSS APPLY 
        sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS st
    CROSS APPLY
        sys.dm_exec_query_plan (qs.plan_handle) AS qp
        where qs.last_execution_time between '2020-09-29 13:16:52.710' and '2020-09-29 23:16:52.710'
    ORDER BY 
        qs.total_worker_time DESC;

--View waiting tasks per connection
SELECT st.text AS [SQL Text], c.connection_id, w.session_id, 
  w.wait_duration_ms, w.wait_type, w.resource_address, 
  w.blocking_session_id, w.resource_description, c.client_net_address, c.connect_time
FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks AS w
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS c ON w.session_id = c.session_id 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle)) AS st 
              WHERE w.session_id > 50 AND w.wait_duration_ms > 0
ORDER BY c.connection_id, w.session_id
GO

-- View waiting tasks for all user processes with additional information
SELECT 'Waiting_tasks' AS [Information], owt.session_id,
    owt.wait_duration_ms, owt.wait_type, owt.blocking_session_id,
    owt.resource_description, es.program_name, est.text,
    est.dbid, eqp.query_plan, er.database_id, es.cpu_time,
    es.memory_usage*8 AS memory_usage_KB
FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks owt
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions es ON owt.session_id = es.session_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests er ON es.session_id = er.session_id
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (er.sql_handle) est
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan (er.plan_handle) eqp
WHERE es.is_user_process = 1
ORDER BY owt.session_id;
GO;
```

Comment: These DMVs are based on cached data so no data from the problem will be available after a restart. Consider enabling the Query store for the database to collect forensic information about query plans. There may be other causes of the symptoms, such as long-term blocking. You could also install [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) and run it next time the problem occurs to identify why the queries are waiting.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman for your valuable inputs. Will try to enable Query store and install sp_whoisactive.

Comment: This could be caused by any number of reasons. TempDB filling up, rogue queries causing blocking and deadlocking, system update, disk space.. What you need to be able  to do it capture diagnostic information and the best way to do is with monitoring software.